# Proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{-n}} = 0$ without switching fraction

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How could I prove that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^{-n}} = 0$$ with L'Hopitals rule without switching $$\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{-n}}$$ to $$\frac{x^{n}}{e^{x}}$$ I tried differentiating and it didn't seem to help!

Could I do it by switching $x$ to $1/x$ and then switching $lim_{x \to \infty}$ to $lim_{x \to 0}$?

Comment: Why wouldn't you switch?

Comment: In my analysis class we haven't proved the $\infty$ over $\infty$ case of L'Hopitals rule yet.

Comment: A way to see it-but without applying L'Hospital's rule-is by setting $u=\frac1x$. The limit is equal to $0$.